# Feature request: search jobs by language requirements?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

SO Jobs currently lists a variety of jobs by criteria such as salary, tech and professional level.

However when listing jobs there is no way to discern easily whether the job requirement in for a specific language (written/vocal).

Scenarios:

- Job advert is written in language X, but is available to candidates who speak languages Y,Z.
- Job advert is written in language X, and is only available to fluent speakers of language X
- Job advert is written in candidates language and no information is specified that the job requires them to be bi-lingual.

These cases are more applicable to remote workers and companies who operate multinationally, especially in Europe.

**Anecdotal evidence**

I saw a job advert posted by company in German, I googled the company and found that they operate day to day in English as they are international.
If I had not done that research I would have avoided that company when applying.

**User journeys**

As a user I would like to add what languages I can write and speak in to my account / profile, so recruiters and alerts are more tailored to me.

As a recruiter, I would like to add language requirements for my job posting, so that I can find the most suitable candidates for that role's communication requirements.

As a user I would like to add languages to the job search filter, so that I can build a more refined list of jobs suited to me.

**Benefits**

Improves candidate matching and prevents wasted applications.

Comment: "only available to native speakers" presumably one would only restrict a job to *fluent* speakers, not native speakers, no?  The latter would be illegal in most places, I would think.

Comment: Yea my bad, I meant fluent.